# Why is analytic continuation practical?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

I was exploring the Riemann Zetta function, and  I observed that $\zeta (s)$ is not normally defined for  $s $ such that $\Re (s) \leq 1$, but analytically continued to the whole complex plane. And the famous Riemann Hypothesis is all about the behavior of the function in the region $0 < \Re(s) < 1$. This means we have accepted the validity of analytic continuation.

Here is my question: why is it valid to assume that a function behaves in the analytically continued domain as it behaves where it is normally defined ? I mean analytic continuation results in counter-intuitive conclusions like "the sum  of all natural numbers is a negative fraction", yet we still use it in our mathematics. Why is that a valid assumption ?

I hope my question is clear. If any of my statements sound absurd or incorrect, I apologize; that's because I just discovered about analytic continuation.

Thanks.

Edit: My question in short is why is $\zeta (-1) = \frac{-1}{12}$ when it should be infinity ?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Analytic continuation is just what it says.  For example for $|x|\lt 1$, we have $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$, so if start with the series (which has that limited domain) the fraction is the definition of the function for all $x\ne 1$.

Comment: It's not correct that $\zeta(s)$ is not normally defined for $s$ such that ${\frak R}(s)\le1$. The analytic continuation of $\sum n^{-s}$ is the normal definition of $\zeta(s)$. To continue herb's comment, while the series $1+2+2^2+\cdots$ may not mean much to you, the fraction $1/(1-2)$ is perfectly sensible. Perhaps we shouldn't treat the analytic continuation as mysterious, but the restricted domain as insufficient.

Comment: @runway44,  May be "normally defined" might not be the right word. What I meant is $\zeta(s) $ blows up to infinity for real part of s less than one by the p-series test right.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, if it makes it a little clearer, look at the Edit.

Comment: The usual series for $\zeta(s)$ blows up there but $\zeta$ itself is conventionally defined on its maximal domain after doing as much analytic continuation as can be done.

Comment: @Ian so do you mean $\zeta$ is piece-wise defined function ?

Comment: $\zeta$ is defined to be the analytic continuation of $\sum n^{-s}$, so it is automatically defined for all $s\ne1$.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be zeta function to realize the
joy of analytic continuation.

You will need to know some background knowledges on power series.

Consider the old geometric series
$$
F(x) = 1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots
$$
as a function of $x$. Just as $\zeta(s)$ sounds nonsense for $s = -1$,
so does, say, $F(2)$.

But, we know that $F(x)$ is written as
$$
F(x) = 1/(1 - x)
$$
for $|x| < 1$.

Now, analytic continuation. The series
$$
1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots
$$
makes sense for $|x| < 1$ (and, differentiable term by term)
and so does the expression 1/(1 - x) for all complex numbers
$x$ except for $x = 1$.

Therefore, F(x) can be uniquely defined (yes, we are
defining) as
F(x) = 1/(1 - x)
for all complex numbers $x \not = 1$.

As you recall that F(x) was nonsense for x = 2 at first,
this sounds a big advance, doesn't it?

Roughly speaking, this depends on the uniqueness of power series
representation; that is, suppose you have two functions
$f(x) = \sum a_{n}x^{n}$ defined on $x \in X$ and
$g(x) = \sum b_{n}x^{n}$ on $x \in Y$, $X \subset Y$,
that are equal over some intersection of $X$ and $Y$.
Well, power series are unique, so f is g for the larger domain $Y$
as well.